# stop multiple threads from acessing a variable

Tags: python, flask, thread-synchronization

I'm using flask for a web application, it was all going well till I had to deal with multiple requests( I am using `threaded=true`)

My problem is if I get two parallel requests then flask will create two threads and they will try to create a file with the same name (I have to use epoch time for file name)

Even if i put lock on the file as soon as the the lock is released the other thread will try to create a file with the same name (as both the threads will have the same `name` value

```
from flask import Flask
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/start', methods=['GET'])
    try:
        # how can i lock a flask's thread from accessing this part so that two threads can't have files with the same name
        name = str(int(time.time()))
        with open(name,'w') as FileObj:
            FileObj.write('Hey')
    except:
        abort(500)

    return "created a file"

def main():
    """
    Main entry point into program execution

    PARAMETERS: none
    """
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',threaded=True)

main()
```

does the flask thread work with `threading.Lock()`, if i put a lock around the `name` will the both parallel threads have different values?

PS: i know i could use `random` name for the files and avoid this problem, but i kind of have to use epoch time that's a pain

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `tempfile.TemporaryFile`? Using epoch-time for filenames is racey -- if the destination location is `/tmp`, for instance, someone else with write access to the directory can predict your name and create a symlink in the destination location pointing to a file they'd like to have overwritten for which you have write access but they don't. Proper tempfile-creation mechanisms use `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` (so not just a random name, but also telling the OS not to let collisions happen if an attacker flooded the namespace, predicted the RNG, &c), and thereby avoid this.

Comment: ...and yes, `threading.Lock()` absolutely will work. Is there a reason you didn't try it before asking here?

Comment: Yeah i have to use epoch time as per the requirement. 
I'm new to flask, so i was not sure if it supports thread locking as it is unstable with multiple threads, will try that out...thanks :)

Comment: Frankly, I'd be chasing down who wrote that requirement and why. Having epoch time as part of your filename is saner than having it be the whole of the name.